# Wheatstone gauge factor calculation?WII load cell

Tags: load-cell, wheatstone-bridge, wii

Currently working with the WIIFIT or WIbalance load cell. For some reason everybody wants to work with these load cell. However, there are no actual datasheet of the load cell used in the device. There are datasheet of imitation load cell(MLC714N), replicas of the load cell of the WII. But they do not have the same sensitivity.

Wondering if anybody has ever accurately calculated it, or knows how to do this? I am thinking to put excitation voltage and use rated weights and calculate the gain(Vout/Vin). Should give me an idea of what the sensitivity of the wii load cell is. However. I am not sure.

[MLC714N load cell spec(imitation load cell for the wii)](http://www.manyyear.com/productdetail.aspx?cateid=154&ProductsID=155#guige)

Comment: Provide links to data sheets.

Comment: There are none that I can find from the actual load cell used in the wii fit. The imitation version of this load cell has a datasheet. However, the imitation is not even close to as sensitive as the original. Furthermore, the imitation load cell has large resistance. It SNR is about 80dB.

Comment: Stumbled upon this article which analyses the WiiBalance:  https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3842432/ not sure if it contains something useful for a single load cell though.